# In JavaScript, how to trim a string preserving new line characters?

Tags: javascript, string

How to trim a string in JavaScript preserving new lines and carriage returns?

```
let str = "  \rA string with carriage returns\n   ";
```

The built-in trim() function removes the new line characters.

```
// Returns "A string with carriage returns"
str.trim()
```

How to remove only leading and trailing spaces ?

Answer (score 1):

> How to remove only trailling spaces ?

Use `String.replace` with a regexp that matches spaces at the end of the string.

```
> "  \rA string with carriage returns\n   ".replace(/ +$/, '')
  '  \rA string with carriage returns\n'
```

> How to remove leading and trailing spaces?

Use `String.replace` with a regexp that matches spaces at the start *and* the end of the string.

```
> "  \rA string with carriage returns\n   ".replace(/^ +| +$/g, '')
  '\rA string with carriage returns\n'
```

Comment: They also need to strip from the beginning of the string, so you also need an Or with `^ +`

Comment: @ZacAnger If they do. They asked for "How to remove only trailing spaces".

Comment: @AKX on the other hand, their example reads `// Returns "A string with carriage returns"`

Comment: @AKX oh, right you are, that is what their post says. I assumed they wanted `str.replace(/^ +| +$/g, '')` because of the title and example code.

Comment: Sorry for my English, I through trailing was both, this is leading and trailing

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution that doesn't use RegEx:

```js
function trimSpaces(str) {
    let i = 0;
    while (str.charAt(i) == ' ') i++;
    let j = str.length;
    while (j > i && str.charAt(j - 1) == ' ') j--;
    return str.substring(i, j)
}
```

which yields:

```js
> trimSpaces("  \rA string with carriage returns\n   ")
'\rA string with carriage returns\n'
```

as expected.

Disadvantage: Less concise, more error prone. Advantage: More predictable performance (many JavaScript RegEx engines are still implemented inefficiently).

Comment: It will predictably be much slower than any native regexp engine. Do you have a source for "many JavaScript RegEx engines are still implemented inefficiently"?

Comment: @AKX Plain wrong. [See this benchmark I quickly put together.](https://jsbench.me/36lfpuk2ic/1) My source is that I recall V8 using a backtracking engine, which can fail catastrophically. It seems there now (as of 2021 apparently) is a fallback one. Still V8 isn't the only JS engine (though SpiderMonkey also seems to ship with a proper RegEx engine). JS will also be compiled to native code by V8, and thus there is no reason for it to inherently be slower than RegEx.

Comment: Fair. However, on that benchmark, on my machine, `regex #2` is fastest.

Comment: (As an aside, you could squeeze out more performance by using `s[i]` instead of `s.charAt(i)`, and even more with `var` instead of `let`...)

Comment: @AKX `s[i]` instead of `s.charAt(i)`? Maybe. But `var` instead of `let`? I doubt that. Why would it be faster?

Comment: @AKX alright, I've benchmarked it, and for some reason, using `var` and `s[i]` is much, much slower on Firefox, and *slightly* faster on Chrome: https://jsbench.me/36lfpuk2ic/2 (interestingly, the SpiderMonkey plain JS is faster than V8's RegEx, which is faster than V8's plain JS...).

Comment: Let and const need to take the TDZ into account, a var is just undefined by value in its scope.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, rather than removing the parts you don't want using a RegEx, you could also capture the parts you do want:

```js
function trimSpaces(str) {
    return str.match(/^ *(.*?) *$/)[1];
}
```

Explanation:

1. `^...$`: start to end
2. `*`: zero or more leading spaces
3. `(.*?)` the actual body - note the lazy `*?`
4. `*`: zero or more trailing spaces)

Disadvantage: [This is slower than AKX's answer and my "plain JS" answer.](https://jsbench.me/36lfpuk2ic/1)